# How to replace with integer variable as part of search pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace some placeholder text within a file with the contents of a list I've built. I step through the list, counting as I go, and do a search which changes depending on the count. The count is an integer that is a part of the search term I use in every loop.

I cannot for the life of me work out what's going on. I've printed everything I can think of and it looks like the search term matches. I've tried multiple methods of replace, but have stuck with the simple replace example to show.

Sample text from the file, get's loaded into variable 'filedata':

`<core:para>ANSWER_1</core:para><core:para>2. Bilateral investment treaties</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_2</core:para><core:para>3. Domestic arbitration law</core:para><p>ANSWER_3</p><core:para>4. Domestic arbitration and UNCITRAL</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_4</core:para><core:para>5. Mandatory provisions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_5</core:para><core:para>6. Substantive law</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_6</core:para><core:para>7. Arbitral institutions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_7</core:para><core:para>8. Arbitrability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_8</core:para><core:para>9. Requirements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_9</core:para><core:para>10. Enforceability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_10</core:para>`

Code:

```
x = 1            
answerlist = ['Oranges', 'Apples', 'Mangos', 'Cherries']

for a in answerlist:
    searchterm = '<core:para>ANSWER_' + str(x) +'</core:para>'
    newdata = filedata.replace(searchterm, a)
    x=x+1
```

For the purpose of the example I've hardcoded the answerlist variable above, but this is dynamically created in a larger loop.

The expected result is:

`<core:para>Oranges</core:para><core:para>2. Bilateral investment treaties</core:para><core:para>Apples</core:para>`
etc

The actual result is:

`<core:para>ANSWER_1</core:para><core:para>2. Bilateral investment treaties</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_2</core:para>`

I've tested the pattern either side of x and that works fine, so the problem appears to be the x, somehow not converting into the string I think it is.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: you haven't actually stated a problem.  I gather that you are seeing results that are not what you want, but you haven't clearly stated what the wrong results are.  For example, in your example above, `Cherries` will get substituted in at the beginning of your text.  Cool.  So what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks, edited to show the expected result now

Comment: in your example code, can you print the full actual result?  Is ANSWER_4 at least substituted out for Cherries?

Comment: also, your list has 4 items, but you have 10 places where you might sub in an answer.  I guess you just want to leave those alone if you don't have an entry in the list for them?

Comment: the reason I asked about the cherries is because in your loop, with the line `newdata = filedata...` you are discarding all previous string replacements with only the most recent replacement.  If you want to keep them all, you need to first assign `newdata = filedata`.  Then do your string substitutions on newdata `newdata = newdata.replace...`

Comment: Good spot, I've updated my code, but it still makes no difference...x as part of the pattern is not recognised.

Comment: Also, I've updated the question with a more comprehensive sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess at what you are trying to do here.  I've taken your example text from above, and assigned it to a string `txt` in the code below.  I can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.split) along with [groupings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (the things in the parentheses) to get the number I'm after to create a list.  I can then iterate over every other element in the list, pull out the integer I'm interested in and reassign that value in the list to my substitution.  In this case, I'm just substituting based on the capital alphabet, but you can put whatever list you want here

```py
txt="""<core:para>ANSWER_4</core:para><core:para>5. Mandatory provisions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_5</core:para><core:para>6. Substantive law</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_6</core:para><core:para>7. Arbitral institutions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_7</core:para><core:para>8. Arbitrability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_8</core:para><core:para>9. Requirements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_9</core:para><core:para>10. Enforceability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_10</core:para><core:para>11. Third parties - bound by arbitration agreement</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_11</core:para><core:para>12. Third parties - participation</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_12</core:para><core:para>13. Groups of companies</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_13</core:para><core:para>14. Multiparty arbitration agreements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_14</core:para><core:para>15. Eligibility of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_15</core:para><core:para>16. Background of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_16</core:para>"""
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
pieces = re.split(r'<core:para>ANSWER_([0-9]+)</core:para>', txt)
for i in range(1, len(pieces), 2):
    idx = int(pieces[i])
    pieces[i] = f'A CAPITAL LETTER: {alphabet[idx]}'
print(''.join(pieces))
```

This will print out:

A CAPITAL LETTER: E5. Mandatory provisionsA CAPITAL LETTER: F6. Substantive lawA CAPITAL LETTER: G7. Arbitral institutionsA CAPITAL LETTER: H8. ArbitrabilityA CAPITAL LETTER: I9. RequirementsA CAPITAL LETTER: J10. EnforceabilityA CAPITAL LETTER: K11. Third parties - bound by arbitration agreementA CAPITAL LETTER: L12. Third parties - participationA CAPITAL LETTER: M13. Groups of companiesA CAPITAL LETTER: N14. Multiparty arbitration agreementsA CAPITAL LETTER: O15. Eligibility of arbitratorsA CAPITAL LETTER: P16. Background of arbitratorsA CAPITAL LETTER: Q

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and sharing your code, always appreciate seeing how others tackle problems. It was my error in the end, a silly mistake that I swore I'd checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to first capture them, then replace it with a desired numbers using a simple for loop and string replace.

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/iHFPV6/1) might help you to capture your desired numbers using a capturing group `([0-9]+)`:

```
(<core:para>ANSWER_)([0-9]+)(<\/core:para>)
```

[image]

#### Test in Python

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<core:para>ANSWER_)([0-9]+)(<\/core:para>)"

test_str = "<core:para>ANSWER_4</core:para><core:para>5. Mandatory provisions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_5</core:para><core:para>6. Substantive law</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_6</core:para><core:para>7. Arbitral institutions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_7</core:para><core:para>8. Arbitrability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_8</core:para><core:para>9. Requirements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_9</core:para><core:para>10. Enforceability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_10</core:para><core:para>11. Third parties - bound by arbitration agreement</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_11</core:para><core:para>12. Third parties - participation</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_12</core:para><core:para>13. Groups of companies</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_13</core:para><core:para>14. Multiparty arbitration agreements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_14</core:para><core:para>15. Eligibility of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_15</core:para><core:para>16. Background of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_16</core:para>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Test in JavaScript

```js
const regex = /(<core:para>ANSWER_)([0-9]+)(<\/core:para>)/gm;
const str = `<core:para>ANSWER_4</core:para><core:para>5. Mandatory provisions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_5</core:para><core:para>6. Substantive law</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_6</core:para><core:para>7. Arbitral institutions</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_7</core:para><core:para>8. Arbitrability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_8</core:para><core:para>9. Requirements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_9</core:para><core:para>10. Enforceability</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_10</core:para><core:para>11. Third parties - bound by arbitration agreement</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_11</core:para><core:para>12. Third parties - participation</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_12</core:para><core:para>13. Groups of companies</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_13</core:para><core:para>14. Multiparty arbitration agreements</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_14</core:para><core:para>15. Eligibility of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_15</core:para><core:para>16. Background of arbitrators</core:para><core:para>ANSWER_16</core:para>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = '<core:para>ANSWER_4</core:para>';
 const regex = /(<core:para>ANSWER_)([0-9]+)(<\/core:para>)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$2");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and sharing your code, always appreciate seeing how others tackle problems. It was my error in the end, a silly mistake that I swore I'd checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works, looks like it was the backslash in the closing tag.

```
x = 1            
answerlist = ['Oranges', 'Apples', 'Mangos', 'Cherries']

for a in answerlist:
    searchterm = '<core:para>ANSWER_' + str(x) + r'</core:para>'
    newdata = filedata.replace(searchterm, a)
    x=x+1
```

Note the r before the last string of the pattern in the searchterm variable construction, which turns the string raw, no need for escape characters.

Comment: I don’t understand. You don’t have any escape characters in the search string you have listed here

Comment: Also the code you put in the question worked when I copied and pasted it unmodified. Is what you are doing actually different from what you have here?